# is it possible to make the "value" self-increase in setTimeout() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

is it possible to make the "value" self-increase in setTimeout() method in Javascript?

My code looks like below code block. I have two for loops in the init() method, and in the inner loop I have setTimeout method to make the function "var myfun = function testFunc(year, value)" to be invoked in every 1 second.

But I still have an attribute called "value" which

1.I want "value" to be increased every time,

2.or make change to "value", then use the new "value" when the next time this function "var myfun = function testFunc(year, value)" been invoked;

But now I found in the function "var myfun = function testFunc(year, value)" I can get the year correctly from the dataset[state], but the "value" is always the same.

Is there any way to make the "value" increased or changed every time?
Really appreciate for any help or answers.

```
...
init();

function init(){
...
  for (var state in dataset) {
    var i=0;
    var value = 18;
    for (var year in dataset[state]) {
       i++;
       setTimeout( "myfun(" + year + "," + value + ")", i*1000);

    }
  }
}

var myfun = function testFunc(year, value){

  // I want "value" to be increased every time, 
  // or make change to "value", then use the new "value" 
  // in the next time invoke this function;
  value++;
  console.log("year:" + year + ",value:"+value);
}
```

Comment: The main problem lies in the fact that you increase the value in "myfun" instead of increasing it in "init". You are always passing the same value and incrementing it by 1.

Comment: **Never** ever pass strings to `setTimeout`. Pass a function!

Comment: Since I want to get the "year" value in myfun and also the I want to do some change to value(not only increasing by 1, there may also some other operations). And I was confused now. is there any way in JS to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's going to be possible if you use `setTimeout` with function callback (which you should do anyway, since string notation is not recommended):

```
function init() {
    // ...
    for (var state in dataset) {
        var i = 0;
        var value = 18;
        for (var year in dataset[state]) {
            i++;
            setTimeout(function() {
                myfun(year, ++value);
            }, i * 1000);
        }
    }
}

var myfun = function testFunc(year, value) {
    console.log("year:" + year + ",value:" + value);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but if i use `setTimeout(function() {
                myfun(year, ++value);
            }, i * 1000);` . Then the year I get in myfun will always be the last one in dataset.   :(

Comment: is there any way in JS to implement this?

Comment: Try this `(function(year) { setTimeout(function() { myfun(year, ++value); }, i * 1000) })(year);`